# If statement checking if a variable is equal to a specific word is getting invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I'm trying to make an easter egg in my calculator program, where if you type my friend johns name in, it prints nerd, but I keep getting invalid syntax on the line the if statement starts. here's what the code looks like:

```
x = input(' ')
if x = John:
    print nerd
else:
    print x
```

please keep in mind i'm using python 2.7, not 3. when I googled it, I only got answers that worked in 3.

Comment: It has nothing to do with using python2 or 3, `if x = John:` would not work on any version.  You might want to study the basics http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = raw_input('enter name ')
if x == 'John':
    print 'nerd'
else:
    print x
```

You are doing an assignment, but you need == to check for equality

Comment: In the future, copy and paste the complete traceback when you encounter an error.  This will help people help solve your problems

Comment: Actually, that didn't work.

Comment: how so? what happened?

Comment: I think you had tabs.. Anyway check my edit, run it.. Works fine for me